# How can I force an abstract to fit on the title page (if there is space) using the AASTeX package?

Tags: formatting, document-classes, aastex

I am trying to format a paper using the AASTeX package. When I typeset the paper with the title, authors, authors' information, and the abstract, the abstract is automatically forced to the second page. I am using the manuscript document class, not the preprint2 mode. 
Apparently, the preprint2 document class with the longabstract style option forces the abstract to the second page whereas the other document classes do not. Judging by eye, my abstract should be able to fit on the title page. Even when I reduce the abstract to one sentence in order to see if it is too long, the abstract is still on the second page.

Is there any way (preferably within AAS conventions) to force the abstract onto the title page?

EDIT: Here is a minimal working example as kindly suggested:

```
\documentclass[manuscript]{aastex}

\begin{document}

\title{Here is an example title with the same number of characters as the title in the paper..}

\author{Sam A. Weiss\altaffilmark{a}, Fake Name Num1\altaffilmark{b}, 
and Fake Name Num2\altaffilmark{c}}
\affil{Department of Physics, This is a Name I Made Up University, 000 Nothing Street,\\ 
New Place, XX, 00000 USA}

\altaffiltext{a}{fakeemail1@fakeplace.edu}
\altaffiltext{b}{fakeemail2@fakeplace.edu}
\altaffiltext{c}{fakeemail3@fakeplace.edu}

\begin{abstract}
Here is the abstract. It should be on page two no matter the length.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
This is needed. Otherwise, nothing will print out.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is behavior by design, so you should not change that  for a paper submitted to the AAS Jour­nals. In case of own use, you can use  `\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\doublespace` to mimic a `manuscript` style  with abstract in the same page..

Comment: Thank you! I am in fact submitting to a journal that does not require AAS standards, but I wanted to try to work within the framework for practice. Your suggestion worked, and it still conforms to the format I need.

Comment: You're welcome. I turned my comment in an answer to remove the question of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is behavior by design, so you should not change that for a paper submitted to the AAS Jour­nals.

In other case, to mimic a `manuscript` style with abstract in the same page you can use:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\doublespace 
...
```

MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}
\doublespace 
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\title{Here is an example title.}
\author{Sam A. Weiss\altaffilmark{a}, Fake Name Num1\altaffilmark{b}, 
and Fake Name Num2\altaffilmark{c}}
\affil{Department of Physics, University of Nowhere, 000 Nothing Street, New Place, XX, 00000 USA}
\altaffiltext{a}{fakeemail1@fakeplace.edu}
\altaffiltext{b}{fakeemail2@fakeplace.edu}
\altaffiltext{c}{fakeemail3@fakeplace.edu}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```